# VMware Workstation Server is not available

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

Got error while run virtual machine hosted by Windows 11:

```
VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.

Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image]

Found solution to fix this error by restarting VMware Workstation Server.
But I can't find touch server in all my PC's that runs VMware workstation 16 and 17 versions.

[image]

Why this service is missing and how to solve problem in general?

Answer (score 0):

The VMware Workstation Server service (aka `vmware-hosted`) was [deprecated in VMware Workstation Pro 16.1](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Shared-VMs-are-back-in-Workstation-16-1/td-p/2811423) and removed in VMware Workstation Pro 17.  That service is used for the Shared VMs feature.  That service should *not* be directly related to the error message you received; the VMware Authorization Service is the relevant one, and restarting that service might help.  If that doesn't work, you alternatively could run VMware Workstation Pro as administrator.